# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'ShapesDataset' on <module '__main__' (built-in)> Mask R-CNN

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train my model on Mac M1 Pro but I keep on getting this error

```
Epoch 1/2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/pauladdai/opt/anaconda3/envs/TensorMask/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "/Users/pauladdai/opt/anaconda3/envs/TensorMask/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'ShapesDataset' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Comment: Can you share code snippet to reproduce the issue.